# Empty page after form submit (PHP & Javascript)

Tags: php, email

I have a form script that sends an email after its been submitted. A javascript removes the form after its been submitted.

But when I submit my form it shows me the empty .php file.

Heres my index.html code:

```html
<!--Here is container with email subscription-->
<div class="container-fluid yellow-container bg-mail">
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
  <h2>Laat hier je email adres achter, zodat wij weten dat je van de partij bent</h2>
  <p>Deze uitnodiging geldt voor jou en een relatie!</p>       

<form action="save.php" id="subscribe-form" method="post" name="subscribe-form">    
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Hier je emailadres" id="email" class="email required">                   
<button class="btn btn-inverse" id="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe">Count me in!</button>
</form>            
         
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

save.php code:

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']))  {
  
  //Email information
  $admin_email = "marco@daretodesign.nl";
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "Inschrijving via Dukdalf", $email . " " . "heeft zich ingeschreven via de website", "Van:" . $email);
}
?>
```

javascript code:

```html
//Subscribe Form


if($('#subscribe-form').length && jQuery()) {
  
    $('form#subscribe-form').submit(function() {

      $('form#subscribe-form .error').remove();

      var hasError = false;

      $('.required').each(function() {
        if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
          var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
          $(this).parent().append('<div class="error">Vul a.u.b. uw email in.'+labelText+'</div>');
          $(this).addClass('inputError');
          hasError = true;
        } else if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
          var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
          if(!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
          var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
          $(this).parent().append('<div class="error">Vul a.u.b. een geldig email in.'+labelText+'</div>');
          $(this).addClass('inputError');
          hasError = true;
          }
        }
      });

      if(!hasError) {
        $('form#subscribe-form input.submit').fadeOut('normal', function() {
          $(this).parent().append('');
        });
        var formInput = $(this).serialize();
        $.post($(this).attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
          $('form#subscribe-form').slideUp("fast", function() {
            $(this).before('<div class="error">Bedankt voor het inschrijven!</div>');
          });
        });
      }

      return false;

    });
```

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: You are trying to send the form via AJAX and yet the page loads blank? This would indicate something wrong with your Javascript. What can you see in the Developer console?

Comment: How to see what happens in my javascript? I cant see any errors..

Answer (score 0):

it shows you your blank php page because you after send email should redirect user to somewhere, perhaps with:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

Regards,
Marcelo